# Long hair collapses with soft body physics in animation

Tags: physics, soft-body

I need to animate a long poly hair and would like it behave a little more like nature, so when I move the head it "follows it's path."
[image: long hair and rig]

I used a **Lattice Modifier** with **Soft Body Physics** to simulate the effect. But as you can see it's collapsing on itself, making it look awful. Would anyone able to help me fix it please?

[Braid Lattice Anim 2.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33254)

Comment: try to adjust the weight paint manually , and rotate the armature to see if it extends back to its normal scale

Comment: Thank you, but it's bending through **Lattice Modifier**, the weight painting is irrelevant. The armature is already rotating on the blend file.

Comment: Ah , i see , sorry i cannot help :)

Comment: Its odd, it isn't maintaining its volume

Comment: @tuliomarchetto can you reupload your blend, a good permanent place is http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the first thing people find when they enable soft body is that it all collapses in on itself. You need to stiffen it up a bit to have it maintain it's structure.

The first thing I would do is enable Stiff Quads and turn up Bending to 3, damp to 20 (under soft body edges) and damping to 12 (under soft body goal).

You will need to experiment more to get it right but that should get you closer.

You might find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofIi4ddHGW0) helpful in explaining some of the options.

Comment: I would even use cloth.